# Table with row scope in html does not work

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to create a table in react which has some horizontal headers like this:
[image]

So i'm writing:

```
<table className="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td />
      <th>EUR</th>
      <th>USD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">AVAILABLE TO TRADE</th>
      <td>€123.154,12</td>
      <td>$3.154,12</td>
      <th scope="row">AVAILABLE TO WITHDRAW (LOCAL)</th>
      <td>€123.154,12</td>
      <td>$3.154,12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. It gives me something like this:
[image]

Why is that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two rows here, but you only have one `<tr>` defined. This makes everything squeeze into one row which is why it looks the way it does in your example.

Try:

```html
<table className="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td />
      <th>EUR</th>
      <th>USD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">AVAILABLE TO TRADE</th>
      <td>€123.154,12</td>
      <td>$3.154,12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">AVAILABLE TO WITHDRAW (LOCAL)</th>
      <td>€123.154,12</td>
      <td>$3.154,12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, note that `<td />` cannot self-close in HTML. However, since you are using React it is valid JSX, but it's probably still a bad practice though. Only self-close tags that *can* self-close in HTML (e.g `<br />` or `<img />`) and for React components.